# Long delay with jquery animation after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a `div` with a width of `0px`. After the user scrolls an `x` distance I want to animate the `div` to `140px`.

When I scroll to that point there is a very long delay before I see the animation. the further I scroll the longer the delay. I'm also setting a containing `div` to fixed at the same point. The fixed item works fine but the animation is always delayed:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="menu-logo">
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
        <nav id="site-navigation" role="navigation">...</nav>

        <div class="right-menu">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var barPos = $('#content').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    var menuHeight = $('.menu-bar').height();
    var topColors = $('#top-colors').height();

    if(barPos <= (topColors+menuHeight)) {
        $('.menu-bar').css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'auto','top':'0px'});
        $('#menu-logo').animate({'width':'140px'});
    } else {
        $('.menu-bar').css({'position':'absolute','bottom':'0px','top':'auto'});
        $('#menu-logo').animate({'width':'0px'});
    }
});
```

Comment: `#content` not appear at `html` at Question ?

Comment: `#content` and `#top-colors` is only used to determine the scroll distance nothing more.

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Have you tried [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)? I think it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The scroll event is fired when the document view or an element has been scrolled.

This means, that your callback will fire multiple times, so every `jQuery.fn.animate` will add a new animation in to the queue.

As an quick'n'dirty fix, you might try calling `jQuery.fn.clearQueue` or `jQuery.fn.stop` before every `jQuery.fn.animate` call.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the animation for a transition inside the css declaration in JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var barPos = $('#content').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
   var menuHeight = $('.menu-bar').height();
   var topColors = $('#top-colors').height();

   if(barPos <= (topColors+menuHeight)) {
      $('.menu-bar').css({
        'position':'fixed',
        'bottom':'auto',
        'top':'0px',
        'width': '140px',
        'transition': 'width 0.4s ease'
   });
   } else {
      $('.menu-bar').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'bottom':'0px',
        'top':'auto'
        'width': '0',
        'transition': 'width 0.4s ease'
     });
   }
});
```